# The cart price rule is not working in magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, cart, price, free-shipping, rules

The cart price rule is not working in magento 2.How to apply cart price rule for free shipping.

Comment: Can you give more information, I think you did not check all validations it should work.
Please let us know if there any customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Set Free Shipping to “For shipment with matching items.”

For more details, go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-free-shipping.html

Comment: I want to hide perticular shipping method if free shipping is available

Comment: please ask another question. I will answer it there and if this helps you can accept this answer